# Cannot decorate AngularJS' ExceptionHandler using TypeScript, as a function isn't recognized as such

Tags: angularjs, typescript, exception

**Background:**
On a project I am working on, we've switched from using AngularJS (1.6.2) with JavaScript, to TypeScript 2.1.5.

We have a decorator applied to the `$exceptionHandler` service that causes JavaScript exceptions to make a call to a common API that send the development team an e-mail; in this way, we can easily see what front-end errors our end-users are encountering in the wild.

**Problem:**
I recently converted this decorator from JavaScript, to TypeScript.  When I try to run the application, I encounter a whitescreen of nothing.  After much debugging I discovered that the issue is because AngularJS expects the `$provide.decorator` to pass a function along with a list of dependencies.  However, an object is instead being observed, and thus forcing Angular to fail-safe.

I diagnosed the problem by setting breakpoints inside of `angular.js` itself; it specifically will fail on line 4809 (inside of function `createInternalInjector(cache, factory)`) due to a thrown, unhandled JavaScript exception, but the part that's actually responsible for the failure is line 4854, inside of function `invoke(fn, self, locals, serviceName)`.  The reason it fails, is because the dependencies passed come across as `['$delegate', '$injector',]`; the function is missing from this set.

Lastly, one thing I considered doing was simply defining a JavaScript function in the class code.  This does not work in my case for two reasons.  First, in our `ts.config`, we have `noImplicitAny` set to true; functions are implicitly of the `any` type.  Additionally, TypeScript itself appears not to recognize `function` as a keyword, and instead tries and fails to compile it as a symbol on class `ExceptionHandler`.

**TypeScript Exception Handler:**

```
export class ExceptionHandler {
    public constructor(
        $provide: ng.auto.IProviderService
    ) {
        $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler`, [
            '$delegate',
            '$injector',
            this.dispatchErrorEmail
        ]);
    }

    public dispatchErrorEmail(
        $delegate: ng.IExceptionHandlerService,
        $injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService
    ): (exception: any, cause: any) => void {
        return (exception: any, cause: any) => {
            // First, execute the default implementation.
            $delegate(exception, cause);

            // Get our Web Data Service, an $http wrapper, injected...
            let webDataSvc: WebDataSvc = $injector.get<WebDataSvc>('webDataSvc');

            // Tell the server to dispatch an email to the dev team.
            let args: Object = {
                'exception': exception
            };
            webDataSvc.get('/api/common/errorNotification', args);
        };
    }
}

angular.module('app').config(['$provide', ExceptionHandler]);
```

**Original JS:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').config(['$provide', decorateExceptionHandler]);

    function decorateExceptionHandler($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', '$injector', dispatchErrorEmail]);
    }

    function dispatchErrorEmail($delegate, $injector) {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            // Execute default implementation.
            $delegate(exception, cause);

            var webDataSvc = $injector.get('webDataSvc');

            var args = {
                'exception': exception,
            };
            webDataSvc.get('/api/common/ErrorNotification', args);
        };
    }
})();
```

**Questions:**
1. In what way can I rewrite the TypeScript Exception Handler to be properly picked up by AngularJS?
2. If I can't, is this an AngularJS bug that needs to be escalated?  I know for a fact I'm not the only person using AngularJS with TypeScript; being unable to decorate a service due to language choice seems like a pretty major problem.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Converting everything to classes isn't the purpose of TS. `config` expects a callback function, not a constructor. And `$exceptionHandler` is factory function, not a class, too. There's just no place for classes.

Comment: I did it this way, because based on my (limited) knowledge of TypeScript, it seems like the correct transcription.  If it's not, then I need to know -  I invite you to provide an answer, per my **questions**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting everything to classes isn't the purpose of TS, there's no use for classes here. JS code is supposed to be augmented with types and probably be enhanced with `$inject` annotation.

```
angular.module('app').config(decorateExceptionHandler);

decorateExceptionHandler.$inject = ['$provide'];

export function decorateExceptionHandler($provide: ng.auto.IProviderService) {
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', dispatchErrorEmail);
}

dispatchErrorEmail.$inject = ['$delegate', '$injector'];

export function dispatchErrorEmail(
    $delegate: ng.IExceptionHandlerService,
    $injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService
): (exception: any, cause: any) => void { ... }
```

`config` expects a regular function, not a constructor. And the reason why the original TS code fails is that `ExceptionHandler` isn't called with `new`, thus `this` is not an object, and `this.dispatchErrorEmail` is not a function.

Comment: That did it.  I didn't know that functions could be exported in a manner similar to classes.  Also, my background is as a C# programmer - I'm used to thinking nigh-purely in terms of putting stuff in classes.  Thanks for expanding my horizons.

Comment: @AndrewGray You're welcome. ES6/TS classes are just syntax sugar for constructor functions. A1 wasn't written with classes in mind, so it heavily uses factory functions. But consider using classes for `service` services and controllers. Btw, there's no real need to export them, they could be just anonymous arrow functions. But exporting them benefits testing a bit.

Comment: Going one step further from this answer, I did a little research on my own code.  Part of my bad assumptions, was that the `class` keyword maps to the IIFE pattern used in the JavaScript I transcribed from; this is not the case.  Rather, the IIFE instead corresponds (very roughly) to either a `namespace`, or a `module` instead.

Comment: Absolutely. ES6 modules deprecate IIFEs, because module scope is local.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it using [TypeScript namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html).  It feels a little cleaner to me, keeping the exception extension functions isolated, and is a nice conceptually coming from something like C#.

exception.module.ts

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import { LoggerModule } from '../logging/logger.module';
import { ExceptionExtension } from './exception.handler';

export const ExceptionModule = angular.module('app.common.exception', [LoggerModule])
    .config(ExceptionExtension.Configure)
    .name;
```

exception.handler.ts

```
import { ILoggerService } from '../logging/logger.service';

export namespace ExceptionExtension {
    export const ExtendExceptionHandler = ($delegate: ng.IExceptionHandlerService, logger: ILoggerService) => {
        return function (exception: Error, cause?: string): void {
            $delegate(exception, cause);
            logger.error(exception.message, "Uncaught Exception", cause ? cause : "");
        }
    };
    ExtendExceptionHandler.$inject = ['$delegate', 'ILoggerService'];

    export const Configure = ($provide: ng.auto.IProvideService) => {
        $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ExtendExceptionHandler);
    };
    Configure.$inject = ['$provide'];
}
```